# subsilver2: Get rid of domain name in Header

Tags: php, phpbb

I am using phpbb subsilver 2 (standard template in fresh installation) On "Forum settings" you can specify a domain name which is in title and Header. I don't want it in my header. How can I get rid of it? I've tried changing some templates, but I can't find which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`styles/subsilver2/template/overall_header.html`](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop/phpBB/styles/subsilver2/template/overall_header.html) on line 8, remove this:

```
<!-- IF not S_VIEWTOPIC and not S_VIEWFORUM -->{SITENAME} - <!-- ENDIF -->
```

And this:

```
<!-- IF S_VIEWTOPIC or S_VIEWFORUM --> - {SITENAME}<!-- ENDIF -->
```

To get it out of the `<title>` tag. To get it out of the site header, on line 147 of the same file, remove this:

```
<h1>{SITENAME}</h1>
```

Don't forget to purge the template cache after you make these changes to ensure the templates are reloaded.

Answer (score -1):

for this you have to update overall_header.html file located;

phpBB/styles/subsilver2/template/overall_header.html

open and find the title tag, remove it or rename it as you want,

```
<title>your-stite-title</title>
```

last you have to login to Administration Control Panel of phpBB and on the home page you find "Purge the cache" Run it to see the effect.